# Export to drive only exports black and white images

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, image, time-series

I am generating a burn severity map for the assessment of the areas affected by wildfires in California and Australia.using this code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b455ba8cf4b5bee822bb7ff8935e6209

My problem is while trying to export the image shown in earth engine editor. The Output is only in black and white.

Can someone help me ?

```
/==========================================================================================
//                                  PREPARE FILE EXPORT

var id = dNBR.id().getInfo();
      
Export.image.toDrive({image: dNBR, scale: 30, description: id, fileNamePrefix: 'dNBR',
  region: area, maxPixels: 1e10});
```

Comment: So you're saying you don't want to export the dNBR data, just a rendered image of it?

Comment: [Exporting images as they appear in the code editor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#exporting-images-as-they-appear-in-the-code-editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the visualization of the exported image. This can be done with `visualize()` command.

Try adding visualization parameters:

```
var greyvis = {
  min: -1000,
  max: 1000,
  palette: ['white', 'black'],
};
```

And in the export command, instead of using `dNBR` as an image input, use `dNBR.visualize(greyvis)`

Note I made the visualization min, max and color palette according to your dNBR greyscale image used. For other exports, you will need to define other visualization parameters.

Comment: thank you very much!